# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass. what happened?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is going on? (Also can one controller be accessed from all view pages?) It looks ok to me, im not sure what happened, but it just retured me this error saying "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass". I am very sad taht this happened.

My controller:

```
  def create
    Venue.create(params[:venue_params])
  end

  def index
    @venues = Venue.all
  end

  def show 
    @venues = Venue.all
  end

  def info
    @venues = Venue.all
  end
```

My view:

```
<table>
    <tr> 
        <th> Venues </th>
    </tr>
    <%= @venues.each do |venue| %>
        <tr>
        <td><%= venue.venue_name %> </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because @venues has no record, you can check it first before you do each with code as follow to prevent an error

```
<table>
    <tr> 
        <th> Venues </th>
    </tr>
    <% if @venues %>
      <%= @venues.each do |venue| %>
        <tr>
        <td><%= venue.venue_name %> </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean it has no record? Like its not recorded in the database?